# Best way to check if some data is present in the redux-store before performing an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react-redux app and one of the actions triggered requires checking the presence of some data in the store. If the data is not present I want to discard the action and don't want to proceed, but if the the data is present we want to fire another action that updates the store.
I was wondering what would be the correct way to do that? The code snippet/pseudo code below mimics something similar.

```
<MyComponent onClick={onClickHandler}/>

onClickHandler = () => {
  if(checkIfDatapresentInStore) {
   // anActionHandler();
  } else {
    anotherActionHandler();
  }
}
```

//Redux-store

```
store = {
    dataPresentInStore: true
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getState` store method. It will return current state present in the store. Then you just need to check the state you are looking for and trigger actions based on that.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Sunny's answer, this is something that's possible to do either within the action creator, or within the component's handler function. It's really up to you if you want to make the `dataPresent` state available to your component or not.

Via action creator in **actions.js**:

```js
// Note: the second argument to action callback is 
// a function that returns the whole store
const conditionalAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Retrieve the whole store object and check what you need from it
  const { dataPresent } = getState();

  // Conditionally dispatch an action
  if (dataPresent) {
    dispatch({ type: "MAIN_ACTION" });
  } else {
    dispatch({ type: "OTHER_ACTION" });
  }
}
```

OR via your example in **MyComponent.js**.